# Pytorch How do you implement Hadamard (element-wise) products within nn.Module, safely?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I need to write an `nn.Module` class with layers that feed into one another. I need to perform an element-wise product on some of the results of my layers, but (emphasis) **I do not need a parametrized layer that does that.**    I need to place it somehow between several parametrized layers.   How can I implement an element-wise product into my model without breaking the gradient or causing other problems?

Element-wise products are also called "Hadamard product".  I have been unable to find a single example of an `nn.Module` doing this kind of product anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the torch.mul function (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mul.html)? This will perform the hadamard product for two inputs of equal size (for unequal sizes broadcasting will be used).
As per usual, executing this function on tensors for whom requires_grad=True, gradients will be calculated properly and stored in the tensor.

As you have not supplied enough information to reconstruct/fully understand the problem you want to solve, I have just come up with an example. Let's say you have a simple CNN in pytorch, but with the twist that (for whatever reason) you would like to mask out the output of the layer in certain regions. This could be implemented in the following way:

```
import torch.nn as nn
class Masking_CNN(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self,input_channels):
       """
       input_channels: int, number of channels in the input 
       """

       super().__init__()        

       #describe the network
       self.conv_layer= nn.Conv2d(input_channels,4,kernel_size=3,padding=1)


   def forward(self,x,mask):
       """
       x: pytorch tensor of size(batch_size,input_channels,input_size,input_size)
       mask: pytorch tensor of size(1,4,input_size,input_size) containing either 0 or 1 
       """
    
       x= self.conv_layer(x)
       x= torch.mul(x,mask) 
       return x
```

So that would be an example on how to integrate the function into your net. All you need is to add the torch.mul function into the forward pass and pass the tensors you want to multiply elementwise (hadamard product) as arguments.

In case you need more narrowed down help concerning your problem, please specify your question and supply more information on your problem.